# display the username after login in angular2

Tags: angular, lumen

I have used this code :
(http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial)

But I have used api which is created in lumen for authentication service.
Now I want to display the username in my home.component.html

Comment: Cool what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried fetch data using api but its show all data. But I want only logged in user data. So I am confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While login set `userid` in local storage and after login get `userid` from local storage.

For examples:

```
localstorage.setItem('userid',this.model.userid);

localstorgae.getItem('userid');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your authentication service, you can store an observable of your current logged in user. This data should be passed from your server (API).

In your component, you import the service, and can do the following:

```
const user = this.userService.getUser();
```

In your html you can do something linke:

```
Hello {{user.first}} {{user.last}} !!
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an authentication service that stores the non sensitive user information in an observable property so that you can reference that anywhere in the application it is needed. Then you can display it on the page after injecting it into your components.